# Android store photos and documents from s3 bucket locally

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a back-end that I have written with Laravel and I am currently writing and Android app which is doing calls to my back-end.

I have some png's and pdf's stored in s3 buckets in my aws account. I need to get the images and documents from the bucket and store them locally on the device as well as displaying them.

I also need to send new png's from the phone to be stored in the s3 bucket.

What is the best way to go around doing this. Are there any useful libraries. I have already added Picasso but that only helps with displaying the image not getting from/storing in the s3 bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the AWS Android SDK for S3. You can consume it in gradle via maven as:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.6.+'
}
```

For example to upload a file to S3:

```
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.util.Log;

  import com.amazonaws.mobile.client.AWSMobileClient;
  import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferUtility;
  import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferState;
  import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferObserver;
  import com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.s3.transferutility.TransferListener;
  import com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client;

  import java.io.File;

  public class YourActivity extends Activity {

      public void uploadData() {

        // Initialize AWSMobileClient if not initialized upon the app startup.
        // AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this).execute();

        TransferUtility transferUtility =
              TransferUtility.builder()
                    .context(getApplicationContext())
                    .awsConfiguration(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getConfiguration())
                    .s3Client(new AmazonS3Client(AWSMobileClient.getInstance().getCredentialsProvider()))
                    .build();

        TransferObserver uploadObserver =
              transferUtility.upload(
                    "s3Folder/s3Key.txt",
                    new File("/path/to/file/localFile.txt"));

        uploadObserver.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {

           @Override
           public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
              if (TransferState.COMPLETED == state) {
                 // Handle a completed upload.
              }
           }

           @Override
           public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                 float percentDonef = ((float)bytesCurrent/(float)bytesTotal) * 100;
                 int percentDone = (int)percentDonef;

                 Log.d("MainActivity", "   ID:" + id + "   bytesCurrent: " + bytesCurrent + "   bytesTotal: " + bytesTotal + " " + percentDone + "%");
           }

           @Override
           public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
              // Handle errors
           }

        });

        // If your upload does not trigger the onStateChanged method inside your
        // TransferListener, you can directly check the transfer state as shown here.
        if (TransferState.COMPLETED == uploadObserver.getState()) {
           // Handle a completed upload.
        }
    }
}
```

For more information:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/add-aws-mobile-user-data-storage.html#add-aws-user-data-storage-upload

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/how-to-storage.html

Answer (score 1):

AWS has a set of libraries that you could use to get and store in the S3 bucket.

You should check: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-mobile/latest/developerguide/getting-started.html

Comment: This is very important AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(this).execute();

Answer (score 1):

For upload file to s3

```
String      ACCESS_KEY="****************",
        SECRET_KEY="****************",
        MY_BUCKET="bucket_name",
        OBJECT_KEY="unique_id";              


AWSCredentials credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY);
            AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(credentials);
            java.security.Security.setProperty("networkaddress.cache.ttl" , "60");
            s3.setRegion(Region.getRegion(Regions.AP_SOUTHEAST_1));
            s3.setEndpoint("https://s3-ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/");
            List<Bucket> buckets=s3.listBuckets();
            for(Bucket bucket:buckets){
                Log.e("Bucket ","Name "+bucket.getName()+" Owner "+bucket.getOwner()+ " Date " + bucket.getCreationDate());
            }
            Log.e("Size ", "" + s3.listBuckets().size());
            TransferUtility transferUtility = new TransferUtility(s3, getApplicationContext());
            UPLOADING_IMAGE=new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Screenshot.png");
            TransferObserver observer = transferUtility.upload(MY_BUCKET,OBJECT_KEY,UPLOADING_IMAGE);
            observer.setTransferListener(new TransferListener() {
                @Override
                public void onStateChanged(int id, TransferState state) {
                    // do something
                    progress.hide();
                    path.setText("ID "+id+"\nState "+state.name()+"\nImage ID "+OBJECT_KEY);

                }

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(int id, long bytesCurrent, long bytesTotal) {
                    int percentage = (int) (bytesCurrent / bytesTotal * 100);
                    progress.setProgress(percentage);
                    //Display percentage transfered to user
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(int id, Exception ex) {
                    // do something
                    Log.e("Error  ",""+ex );
                }

            });
```

For downloading image

https://github.com/jontyankit/Glide-Amazon-Image-Load